# How to decide 1x size for image?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one ImageView but the width and height are not constant. Both will change as per device width and height. (Height of ImageView is 1/3 of screen size and width is complete device width)

Example:

| Proper Colors | Height | Width |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone SE | 375 | 222.5 |
| iPhone 11 Pro Max | 414 | 298.67 |
| iPhone 12 Pro Max | 428 | 308.67 |
| iPhone 12 | 390 | 281.33 |

As we see, width and height are varying so in this scenario what should be size for 1x image. Once we get 1x size then 2x and 3x sizes we can find easily.

Note: If width and height is fixed then I know how to find 1x, 2x and 3x.

Example: If imageView is 20x20 then, 1x = 20x20, 2x = 40x40, 3x = 60x60, But in above scenario width and height is not constant.

Comment: Why not just choose some image size, for example 400pt wide at 1x, and scale that to the screen size? Almost all devices are 2x or 3x, so 1x might not even need to be included. You could have 800px and 1200px wide images. And for the image-screen ratios, you could either accept that the ratio will not be the same on all screens, or crop the image to a certain ratio then fit to screen. Also, [this](https://ios-resolution.com) may be useful for all the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: If width and height is fixed then I know how to find 1x, 2x and 3x. Example: If imageView is 20x20 then, 1x = 20x20,2x = 40x40,3x = 60x60

@1x, @2x, @3x has more to do with the pixel density of the screen and not the size of the image. If the same sized image is displayed on a higher resolution screen then iOS will automatically choose a @3x version of the asset. Think of video quality on YouTube, a 720p and 1080p has the same size. But the 1080p video is more **clear**.

> But in above scenario width and height is not constant.

As to dealing with the changing size of the screen, you need to decide before hand how your images should be displayed. This is a UI designing concern. `UIImageView` has various [`ContentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode) options that you can use. For example,

> scaleAspectFit: The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

So if you use `scaleAspectFit` then on larger screen sizes you will have more blank space to the sides of the image.

Also, please take a look at Apple's Human Interface Guidelines for [Image Size and Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) and [1x, 2x and 3x Image Scaling on iOS Explained](https://learnappmaking.com/image-scaling-ios-how-to/#:%7E:text=You%20provide%20higher%20resolution%20image,a%20high%2DPPI%20iPhone%20model.) blog post.

> The coordinate system iOS uses to place content onscreen is based on measurements in points, which map to pixels in the display. A standard-resolution display has a 1:1 pixel density (or @1x), where one pixel is equal to one point. High-resolution displays have a higher pixel density, offering a scale factor of 2.0 or 3.0 (referred to as @2x and @3x). As a result, high-resolution displays demand images with more pixels.
>
> [image: pixel density visualization for 1x, 2x and 3x images]

> When you can fit more pixels on the same screen real-estate, you also need higher resolution images. This is where 1x, 2x and 3x come in. You provide higher resolution image files for the same assets, which are automatically selected by iOS when your app runs on a high-PPI iPhone model.